# Why doesn't U-Boot disable the console output

Tags: console, boot, bootloader, u-boot, silent

I have this system which is accessed by a serial Debug Port. I want to disable all of the output, that was made during the U-Boot boot. Therefore there is the

> setenv silent 1

parameter, which i put into the BOOTCMD string like:

> #define CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND   " setenv silent 1;" \
>
> "bootm "

and there is the

> #define CONFIG_SILENT_CONSOLE

command, neither one is working (*the lines printed out are still the same and the boot time didn't change*). Does somebody see the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U-Boot is doing exactly what it should (silencing the output) with the following command:

> #define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS \

```
        "silent=1\0" \
```

---

see [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356844/how-to-disable-serial-consolenon-kernel-in-u-boot/64583919#64583919?newreg=0df51e20b39a448094cbb70fe356e4ec)

Answer (score 3):

For my target, U-Boot baseline 2013.10, silent environment variable works at kernel boot time, but it needed more defines:

```
#define CONFIG_SILENT_CONSOLE 
#define CONFIG_SYS_DEVICE_NULLDEV
#define CONFIG_SILENT_CONSOLE_UPDATE_ON_SET
```

That also killed kernel serial console after successful boot, until I added

```
#define CONFIG_SILENT_U_BOOT_ONLY
```

Refer to [README.silent](http://git.denx.de/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=u-boot.git;a=blob;f=doc/README.silent;hb=v2013.10) for more info.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't change a thing. Can you please tell me on which position you put them in your board-header file ? Maybe it's because of this. Thanks

Comment: Those lines went in before #include "config_cmd_default.h". But I don't think their position will matter. For your debug, you may try doing "setenv silent 1" at command line. That should lock the console until reboot, it may tell what is / is not working for you. Also note you can do "setenv bootcmd 'setenv silent 1;bootm'" (then "run bootcmd") at command line, in place of CONFIG_BOOTCOMMAND+rebuild. I trust you are seeing build time stamp change on each u-boot rebuild?

Comment: Hmmm... yes as mentioned in the top-post I've already applied the bootcommands. And I checked them by entering U-Boot during boot and viewing the environmental variables with "printenv". So these commands like setenv silent 1 was already here. BTW: the command "setenv verify n", which i put into the bootcommands is working.

Comment: I found that having "silent=1" already set in persistent storage had no effect on the next reboot. Doing "setenv silent; setenv silent 1" did have effect. This seems like the purpose of CONFIG_SILENT_CONSOLE_UPDATE_ON_SET. I think you would find it useful to experiment by setting environment variables at the command line.

Comment: You were talking about rebooting, actually I want to generate Images where the device with the given settings already have an effect on the very first boot (like the setenv verify n did)